# PHP header redirect + no index

Tags: php, redirect

How would you go about redirecting via PHP's header function and also making sure that the page itself is not indexed? I came up with the following two options and wanted to get your opinion if one should be preferred to the other OR if there is an even better way of doing this.

**Option 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <?php 
      header('Location: https://www.example.com');
      exit;
    ?>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Option 2**

```
<?php 
  header("X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow", true);
  header('Location: https://www.example.com');
  exit;
?>
```

I really appreciate your thoughts on this.

P.S. Am I correct to assume that php header redirect is always 302 by default?

Comment: The page you're redirecting *to* should not be indexed? Or the one doing the redirecting?

Comment: @deceze The page that contains the header function should not be indexed.

Comment: Since the URL is just responding with a redirect and no content, there's nothing to index in the first place.

Comment: @deceze I wish, but when checking the SERPs the pages do show up with "No title" and no meta description probably because they are being linked to from other pages within the same website.

Comment: what about if you set another header which returns the status code 301 (permanent redirect)? Eventually the pages should get de-indexed I think.

Comment: @ADyson Had a similar thought but since the link can change quite frequently I think 302 is the better solution here.

Comment: According to https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection (I don't know how accurate this is, but it seems reasonable) then you stand much more chance of it being de-indexed if you use a 301. Why does the link you're redirecting to change frequently? What's going on here? N.B. I've seen situations where a URL returns a 301 to another URL, which in turn returns a 301 to another URL etc until you finally hit the current version. So that's an option if you frequently change the location of your resource, but don't want the old URLs to show up in searches.

Comment: @ADyson Because those are sponsor links and whenever a sponsor changes we don't want to change it across all pages but rather in once place, hence /out/sponsor-gold, /out/sponsor-silver etc.

Comment: Store the sponsor links in fields in your DB and use PHP to retrieve the links from the DB and insert them into your page instead of hard-coding them anywhere. Then all pages with that code snippet in them always render the link stored in the database. This means whenever the sponsor changes you just update the database field, and job done, just like any other dynamically generated content. No need for an intermediary page and redirect nonsense. This is a classic example of an X-Y problem.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, this is an option but I don't think my approach is that unusual either. If you had to choose one of the options above, which one would you prefer or are both the same to you?

Comment: You can use robots.txt http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html file for noindex and header function for redirect.

Comment: I wouldn't like to speculate as to whether it's unusual, but from your description it's certainly unnecessary. All you do is add complexity and indirection, and make your users consume time and bandwidth making 2 HTTP requests where one would do the job, as well as creating for yourself this SEO problem which doesn't need to exist. I wouldn't choose either of your options. I've suggested the approach I would take to resolve this in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

Take a step back and use a different approach entirely:

Store the sponsor links in fields in your database, and use PHP to retrieve the links from the DB and insert them into your page (instead of hard-coding them anywhere).

That way, all pages with that code snippet in them always render the link currently stored in the database. This means whenever the sponsor changes you just update the database field, and job done. This is just like any other dynamically generated content.

The advantages of this are:

1. Maintenance is easy - when the sponsor link changes, just update
   the DB record, instead of having to edit your PHP file directly. You
   can even make an admin page so a non-technical user can do it.
2. There is no need for an intermediary page and redirects. This solves
       your SEO problem, since there's no blank page to be indexed
3. You
           save your users time and bandwidth (especially valuable on slow
           and/or data-capped mobile connections) because they connect directly
           to the sponsor's website instead of making a needless extra HTTP
           request to your dummy page before being redirected.